# js doesn't recognize an id element om HTML

Tags: javascript, html

**i have this function on js:**

```
function get_days(){
    var daysDiv = document.getElementById("days"); // here is the error
    content = "";
    for (i = 1; i <= numberOfDaysInMonth; i++){
        content += "<li>" + i + "</li>";
    }
    daysDiv.innerHTML = content;
}
```

**this is what I have in the HTML code:**

```
<ul id="days"></ul>
```

the error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting
> 'innerHTML').

I don't know why, but it thinks that the variable daysDiv is null.

Comment: Are you executing your JS before the `<ul>` has been created?

Comment: I need more information, please show your html file, this code is working

Comment: `<script src="youscript.js" defer></script>`

Comment: I will copy my HTML file

Comment: Try moving `<script src="JS/calendar_table.js"></script>` from where you have it now to right before `</body>`

Comment: how can I edit my question?

Comment: There is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71213152/edit) link at the bottom of it. Side Note - your variable is called `div` but you really have a `ul`.

Comment: `defer` does not mean the script is executed after DOM is ready. It simply means the script will be executed after the document has been parsed, and _before_ DOMContentLoaded is fired. Therefore, your script is attempting to query for an element that doesn't exist in the DOM: because the DOM isn't ready when it is being executed.

Comment: Thanks j08691!! I get it now, it works :)